# How to recover /usr/libexec/java_home executable on Mac OS X 10.8.5?

Tags: macos, mac, java, jdk

Today I accidentally delete the `/usr/libexec/java_home` executable on my Mac OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) while trying to install latest JDK. Then, I realized that homebrew (package manager) and some other apps needs that binary.

Where can I find or recover that file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. It was just a symlink and original file was still alive in this directory:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/
```

So, simply put back the symlink using the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home /usr/libexec/.
```

**Update:**
The `System/Library/Frameworks` directory holds the framework files which provide interfaces needed to write software for Mac. You can learn more about this directory on official [OS X Frameworks documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html).

Comment: What's the System/Library/Frameworks folder do anyway?

Comment: Hey @Pacerier, I have updated the answer and added a link for the docs.

Comment: For me it is `Versions/A`, no idea why. There is no `Versions/Current`.